# Is there a command\tool to follow calls of REST endpoints from service to service?

Tags: rest, endpoint

I test some service endpoints which when I launch them, they call another endpoint on another service, and this one calls another endpoint on another service, and it may have number of more hops on their way.

How can I trace these calls, including the requests and response bodies?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no authentication for the APIs, it will be easy to track the API calls via the Chrome/Firefox browsers' network tab after executing the API in the browser or generating a HAR file from a browser.

Comment: Those are authenticated calls.